# How using DOM assign value to variable in JS?

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm working on Rock,Paper and Scissors project. I'm stuck at this problem.  I don't know how to assign value to variable using DOM. When user clicks rock button the value of rocks hould be passed to variable and the variable should be used in playRound function. I don't understand how to fix the problem. When I click to button nothing works.

```js
//Gives the random item to item var
function computerPlay() {
  const theArr = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  var item = theArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  return item;
}

//Returns players selection
function playerPlay(e) {
  var pItem = e;
  console.log(`${e}`);
  return pItem;
}



var r = document.querySelector('.rock').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);
var p = document.querySelector('.paper').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);
var s = document.querySelector('.scissors').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);

var play = document.querySelector('.playbtn').addEventListener('click', playRound);

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerPlay();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper' || playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors' ||
    playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
    window.alert(`${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection} YOU LOST!`);
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    window.alert(`${computerSelection} and ${playerSelection} it is a DRAW!`);
  } else {
    window.alert(`${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection} YOU WIN!!!`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="rock">ROCK</button>
  <button class="paper">PAPER</button>
  <button class="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
</div>

<div class="play-btn">
  <button class="playbtn">PLAY</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not fetching the player's selection anywhere, and calling `playerPlay()` manually does not work, because it is supposed to be a callback.
I changed your code a little and the `play` button can be removed because it is kind of ambiguous. Try this out:

```
function computerPlay() {
    const theArr = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    var item = theArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    return item;
}

//Returns players selection
function playerPlay(e) {
   var playerSelection = e.srcElement.classList[0];
   console.log(playerSelection);
   computerSelection = computerPlay();

   if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper' || playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors' || playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
      window.alert(`${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection} YOU LOST!`);
   } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
      window.alert(`${computerSelection} and ${playerSelection} it is a DRAW!`);
   } else {
      window.alert(`${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection} YOU WIN!!!`);
   }
}

var r = document.querySelector('.rock').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);
var p = document.querySelector('.paper').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);
var s = document.querySelector('.scissors').addEventListener('click', playerPlay);
```